# Loading all the tables into a strongly typed dataset, defined in an XSD?

Tags: c#, xsd, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

What I want to do is cache entire tables stored in the database, as in all the rows. I am using XSDs to define strongly typed datasets and defining custom get() set() operations in associated tableadapter partial classes.

What I would like to do is iterate through all the tableadapters in a dataset and execute the same command in each. Not possible it seems, there is no collection of tableadapters.

So how else can I basically fill every single datatable in the strongly typed dataset in a dynamic way?

Many thanks,
Fugu

Comment: **Why??** The database (whichever it is you're using) typically does a pretty good job already to cache what's needed most frequently. Why add yet another layer on top, where you might introduce bugs and/or suboptimal algorithms? Why not leave that job to the database and just do **your** work (your business specific code) instead of re-inventing infrastructure plumbing that's already in place....

Comment: Because it will mean less communication with the database.

Comment: For future visitors to this question; his is almost always a horrifically bad idea. Data lives in databases, not a clunky collection of heavyweight client side objects designed for small amounts of data retrieval, tracking and storage back in the database from whence it came

Comment: @CaiusJard I've started down this path as a way to make an application more responsive so I'm curious if you know of any resources you could point me to or more detailed reasons why this is almost always a bad idea, and why "almost always" instead of "always"?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a [TableAdapterManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384426.aspx) ?

It contains a Property for each of your TableAdapters.

Comment: It contains a property for each tableadapter, but there is no collection of these properties. How do I iterate through each TableAdapter, filling each table as I go? If I use reflection to get all the properties, that doesn't work either because there are some properties which are not table adapters.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a 10 year old question, but thanks to tableadapters being generated as `partial` you can relatively easily do something like:

- Double click your dataset to switch to code view
- Edit the code like:

```
//make sure you're in the TableAdapters namespace rather than the dataset one
namespace YourAppNamespace.YourDataSetNameTableAdapters
{
    //define in this interface the common things you want to have 
    //access to on all your ITableAdapters 
    public interface ITableAdapter
    {
        SqlConnection Connection { get; set; }

        bool ClearBeforeFill { get; set; }

        int Update(YourDataSetName ds);

    }

    //then mention every tableadapter here, as an empty partial, just to mark it as implementing the interface
    public partial class My1TableAdapter : ITableAdapter { }
    public partial class My2TableAdapter : ITableAdapter { }
    public partial class My3TableAdapter : ITableAdapter { }
```

You don't have to do anything else; you can now refer to your tableadapters as ITableAdapters and access the properties you declared here.

If you want all the tableadapters in a list, you can also pull some trick like enumerating the components on the form (note; they aren't controls) or reflectively looking at the proeprties of the tableadapter manager:

```
        List<ITableAdapter> _ta = new List<ITableAdapter>();
 


        foreach(var p in tableAdapterManager.GetType().GetProperties())
            if((typeof(ITableAdapter).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType)))
                _ta.Add((ITableAdapter)p.GetValue(tableAdapterManager));
```

Note that you don't "iterate every tableadapter in a dataset" - tableadapters don't live in datasets, datatables live in datasets; tableadapters are in a different namespace and aren't exactly anything to do with a dataset in the same way that a tap isn't necessarily related to a bucket